# Android Push notification mechanism

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

I would like to add push notification to my application. More specific my app needs to check every X minutes if there are some fresh data on the server (for example via a volley call) and if yes a notification should appear on the user screen.

I have search about this but i can not understand how i make my app "running" when it is not open in order to ask the server for fresh data.

Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Send push notification (payload type) with High Priority. This will wake-up the app in any condition.

Comment: use background services to check the data.